# Listing multiple columns in a single row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
(select ID,EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID,EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_TYPE,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID ORDER BY ID ) AS SEQNUM
from AC_POS_TRANSACTION_TRK aptt WHERE [RESULT] ='Success'
GROUP BY ID, EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID,EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_TYPE )
```

Hello,

On above query, I want to get rows of transaction id's which has seqnum=1 and seqnum=2

But if that transaction id has no second row (seqnum=2), I dont want to get any row for that transaction id.

Thanks!!

Something like this

[image: My Aim]

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: What you want to add to your query is an Exists statement.

Comment: so what you want is either no row per group or 2 rows (or at least 2 rows) per group, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if this is correct without you table definition, but my understanding is that you want to EXCLUDE records if that record has an entry with seqnum=2 -- you can't use a where clause alone because that would still return seqnum = 1.

You can use an exists /not exists or in/not in clause like this

```
 (select ID,EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID,EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_TYPE,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID ORDER BY ID ) AS SEQNUM
    from AC_POS_TRANSACTION_TRK aptt WHERE [RESULT] ='Success'
    
 and not exists ( select 1 from  AC_POS_TRANSACTION_TRK a where a.id = aptt.id 
                     and a.seqnum = 2)

    GROUP BY ID, EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID,EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_TYPE )
```

basically what this does is it excludes records if a record exists as specified in the NOT EXISTS query.

Comment: Not exists? I guess exists since displayed rows should have a.seqnum = 2

Comment: Hello, I got below error     "Invalid column name 'SEQNUM'." Thanks for solution I got the point :) Actually, my aim is If any transaction id has seqnum 1 and 2, list that rows, if transaction id has only seqnum=1, do no show that row.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job.

```
With Qry As (
    -- Your original query goes here
),
Select Qry.* 
From Qry 
Where Exists (
    Select * 
    From Qry Qry1 
    Where Qry1.EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID = Qry.EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID 
    And Qry1.SEQNUM = 1
)
And Exists (
    Select * 
    From Qry Qry2 
    Where Qry2.EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID = Qry.EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID 
    And Qry2.SEQNUM = 2
)
```

BTW, your original query looks problematic to me, specifically I think that instead of a GROUP BY columns those columns should be in the PARTITION BY clause of the OVER statement, but without knowing more about the table structures and what you're trying to achieve, I could not say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

One option you can try is to add a count of rows per group using the same partioning critera and then filter accordingly. Not entirely sure about your query without seeing it in context and with sample data - there's no aggregation so why use `group by`?

However can you try something along these lines

```
select * from (
    select ID,EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID,EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_TYPE,
    Row_Number() over(partition by EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID order by ID) as SEQNUM,
    Count(*) over(partition by EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID) Qty
    from AC_POS_TRANSACTION_TRK
    where [RESULT] ='Success'
)x
where SEQNUM in (1,2) and Qty>1
```